# Pointer Condition while(*s1++=*s2++)

Tags: c, pointers

```
int main()
{
char str1[] = "Overflow";
char str2[] = "Stack";
char *s1 = str1, *s2=str2;
while(*s1++ = *s2++)
printf("%s", str1);
return 0;
}
```

When this condition breaks

```
(while(*s1++ = *s2++))
```

PLease explain the logic

The output coming is

[image]

Comment: Why do *you* think it breaks?

Comment: @n.m. I have put the output screenshot

Comment: That's not what I have asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*s1++`, in this variable, `*` is having higher precedence than  `++`.
In below code,

```
while(*s1++ = *s2++); //There should be a semicolon.Your code does not has.
```

1. `*s1 = *s2` is evaluated first.
2. Almost every expression in C returns a value. So `*s1 = *s2` returns a value which is the first character and its obviously not null. `while()` loop is executed.
3. Then `s1` and `s2` are incremented.
4. When `s2` reaches the end of string, `*s2` returns `'\0'` which is assigned to `s1`. `*s1=*s2`. Now this expression also return a value which is `'\0'` and `while('\0')` loop terminates.

Comment: Nitpicking: Instead of `null` better use `NUL` (one ell) or `'\0'` or simply `0` to make sure it's not mixed up with `NULL` which is something different.

Comment: The first sentence is not true. A postfix `++` has a higher precedence than a prefix `*`. But it is executed after the evaluation, being a postifx operator.

Comment: `* is having higher precedence than ++`: is completely wrong.

Comment: If `++` would have lower precedence than `*`, the character value at the pointer would be incremented instead of the pointer.... So the answer is completely wrong.

Answer (score 3):

This while loop relies on the fact that non-zero evaluates as true in any conditional expression in C.

It's probably clearer to work the other way, from the more obvious way of doing this operation, to this shorthand.

You can start with:

```
while(*s2 != '\0')
{
    *s1 = *s2;
    s1++;
    s2++;
}
```

This means 'while s2 hasn't reached a terminator character, keep copying characters from s2 to s1. Move both pointers forward after each copy to get ready for the next copy.

However, this can be shortened by including the increment operation in the same line as the copy. This is safe because it's a *post-increment* operation. It won't evaluate till the copy has already been done. The code now looks like this:

```
while(*s2 != '\0')
{
    *s1++ = *s2++;
}
```

Now, given that nonzero is equivalent to true, we can simplify further. The *s2 != '\0' is equivalent to just *s2 on its own.

```
while(*s2)
{
    *s1++ = *s2++;
}
```

Finally, we can move the *copy itself* into the while statement. The while statement itself will copy the character from *s2 to *s1 and then evaluate *s1 as before. The increment then happens afterwards, and round it goes. So our code looks like this:

```
while(*s1++ = *s2++);
```

So.. in your case you need a semicolon after your while statement, or it will print multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

Precedence of `*` operator is higher than `++` operator,due to this in your expression

```
while(*s1++ = *s2++)
```

s1 get assigned first by s2 before increment so order of Evaluation will be

1.`*s1=*s2;`

2.`s1++,s2++`

3 `printf("%s",str1)`,here value of str1 get changed due to operation 1

4.While loop Treminating condition comes when s2 reached to end `'\0'` and this value get assigned to s1 due to `*s1=*s2` specified above and value of s1 become null => `s1='\0'` and while loop gets terminate

Comment: The first sentence is not true. A postfix `++` has a higher precedence than a prefix `*`. But it is executed after the evaluation, being a postifx operator.

Comment: See comment to the above. Your answer is just as wrong, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

This loop would copy contents of `str2` into `str1`:

```
while(*s1++ = *s2++);
```

If would stop when it will encounter last byte in str2 (which would be 0).

In other words, `str1[] = "Overflow"` would become `str1[] = "Stacklow"`.

---

**UPDATE**: more detailed explanation.

- On first loop, you copy just 1 character from `str2`, which is `S`. So `str1` from `Overflow` becomes `Sverflow`.
- 2nd loop, it becomes `Sterflow`.
- 3rd loop, it becomes `Starflow`.
- 4th loop, it becomes `Stacflow`.
- 5th loop, it becomes `Stacklow`.

Note that those are the lines visible in your screenshot.

After that, 0 byte is encountered and copied to `str1`, so it becomes `Stack\0ow`, but you don't print it. If you were to print it, it would print just `Stack`.

Comment: I have put the output screenshot

Comment: And you're lucky that Stack is smaller than Overflow otherwise, you'd have a buffer overflow which is bad (tm)

Answer (score 0):

It will loop till it encounter the string terminator('\0') in s2

```
while(*s1++ = *s2++)
printf("%s", str1);

while(*s1++='S') prints "Sverflow"
while(*s1++='t') prints "Sterflow"
while(*s1++='a') prints "Starflow"
while(*s1++='c') prints "Stacflow"
while(*s1++='k') prints "Stacklow"
while(*s1++='\0') ends loop
```