# Pointer in C (while(*s1++ = *s2++))

Tags: c, pointers, operator-precedence

For the below program

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str1[] = "India";
    char str2[] = "BIX";
    char *s1 = str1, *s2=str2;
    while(*s1++ = *s2++)
        printf("%s", str1);

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

How the condition in while loops gets evaluated? I can see the similar post in stack overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995338/pointer-condition-whiles1-s2), but they didn't give explanation how  * operator has greater precedence than postfix operator.But actually, postfix operator has greater precedence than * (Derefernce) operator. Precedence table for our reference [here](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm)

Please explain how this code prints below output

```
BndiaBIdiaBIXia
```

Comment: Not to invalidate the question... but why would you ever use this code?

Comment: `*s1++` is `*(s1++)`

Comment: postincrement precedence doesn't matter much here because it is *post*increment. So, in a nutshell, the compiler realizes *first* that it needs to increment the pointers *after everything else is done*. The increment is still done *after* the expression is evaluated.

Comment: Your confusion might be because the (accepted) answer to the  linked question was just simply plain wrong (like most other answers to that question).

Comment: This is known as  `K&R strcpy()` (without the printf, only the "empty" loop: `while(*s1++ = *s2++) {;}` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operator precedence and order of execution is not necessarily the same thing.

```
*s1++ = *s2++
```

Is evaluated by the compiler as follows:

1. Compiler sees "++" which has the highest precedence. As it is the *post-increment operator*, it simply makes note of the fact that the pointer needs to be incremented *after* the evaluation of the expression is done.
2. Compiler sees "*" operator, telling it that it should dereference s2, and use that as the RHS
3. Same on the left side of the assignment, the `char` at s1 is set to the `char`'s value at s2
4. Compiler gets back to it's note that pointers need to be incremented after expression evaluation and does so.

Even if `++` is of higher precedence as `*`, it is still done last. Precedence here just means the post-increment operation has to be done to the *pointer*, and not to the *value at the pointer*

Answer (score 1):

The assignment inside the condition plus the `%s` format string explains this:

Splitting up the condition

```
c2 = s2;
c1 = s1;
condition = *c1 = *s2;
++s1, ++s2;
```

So the condition evaluates to whether the pointer `s2` does not point to the null character.

This is the case for `B`, `I` and `X`.  The third iteration, `s2` will be at the null terminator of the string literal `BIX`.

For each iteration, the content of `str1` is printed.  For the first run, the first character has been overwritten by the `B` from `BIX`.  For the second run, the second character has been overwritten by the `I`.  For the last run, you get `BIXia`.  If you would have appended a newline this would have been more clear: `printf("%s\n", str1);` would print each iteration on separate lines.

Note: it might be possible that you confuse `=` with `==`, and that you're really searching for the mismatch; this is a very common mistake.

```
while(*s1++ == *s2++) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I don't get you wrong, you have to write

```
while(*s1++ == *s2++)
    printf("%s",str1);
```

Otherwise you are just replacing and not comparing str1[i] with str2[i].

Answer (score 0):

The unary asterisk '*' operator has a right-to-left association and not left-to-right association as the postfix increment '++' operator. For this reason the unary asterisk is evaluated first in this example. This has to do with how LALR parsers work.

See http://www.swansontec.com/sopc.html